# Powershell Export Get-ADUser LocaleID issue

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to export `ADUser` attributes but this one will not return the right results in the excel but it shows okay on the Powershell.

**Code:**

`Get-ADUser username -properties * | Select-Object Name,LocaleID`

**Result:**

`Name:User Name`
`LocaleID:{3}`

But when I export it to CSV then the result is different:

**Code:**

`Get-ADUser username -properties * | Select-Object Name,LocaleID|Export-Csv .\Desktop\aduser.csv`

The result in CSV for LocaleID was: `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection` instead of {3} or 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LocaleID is a multi value property you need to expand it first.
Also, don't load all properties when all you need is just one just the LocaleID property.

```
Get-ADUser username -Properties LocaleID  | 
Select-Object Name,@{n='LocaleID';e={$_.LocaleID -join ';'}}|
Export-Csv .\Desktop\aduser.csv
```